I want to be able to access the context instance that shows in the widget... I want to use it in a list widget
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ButtonData {
  final String text;
  final Color? color;

  ButtonData({
    required this.text,
    required this.color,
  });
}

final List<ButtonData> buttonData = [
  ButtonData(text: 'AC', color: Color(0xFFB71C1C)),
  ButtonData(text: '⌫', color: Color(0xFF757575)),
  ButtonData(text: '%', color: Color(0xFF757575)),
  ButtonData(text: '/', color: Color(0xFF757575)),
  ButtonData(text: '7', color: null),
  ButtonData(text: '8', color: null),
  ButtonData(text: '9', color: null),
  ButtonData(text: '×', color: Color(0xFF757575)),
  ButtonData(text: '4', color: null),
  ButtonData(text: '5', color: null),
  ButtonData(text: '6', color: null),
  ButtonData(text: '-', color: Color(0xFF757575)),
  ButtonData(text: '1', color: null),
  ButtonData(text: '2', color: null),
  ButtonData(text: '3', color: null),
  ButtonData(text: '+', color: Color(0xFF757575)),
  ButtonData(text: '0', color: null),
  ButtonData(text: '00', color: null),
  ButtonData(text: '.', color: null),
  ButtonData(text: '=', color: Color(0xFF757575)),
];

So is there a way I can do use the context instance in this list, or what alternative way can i do that will enable me access the context instance, because what i majorly want to do is to access the Theme.of(context).colorScheme property so it's able to

If mapping data from any Controller/Provider class, you might use the Application context to access the theme.
*** Declare NavigatorState as GlobalKey**
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

*** Use the key as navigatorKey in MaterialApp**
return MaterialApp(
   navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
   ...
);

*** Use the key to access Application context anywhere**
//access context anywhere using the navigatorKey
var theme = Theme.of(navigatorKey.currentContext!);

final List<ButtonData> buttonData = [
  ButtonData(text: 'AC', color: theme.colorScheme.primary,),
  ...
];

** other wise you need to use local widget context to access theme etc.

but there are about 20 buttonData, i can't do this for each of em, can i?
I'm using the buttonData as an Array of objects which is being mapped over in another component for cleaner code

Yes, you can pass a list of widgets into a listview.
But what is your purpose in using context here? Do you want to pass a BuildContext to model data and then use it in a widget to access the theme? Can you please explain a bit here?

yes that is why i need the context. I basically want to be able to dynamically change the color of each of the ButtonData objects or classes depending on if it's in light mode or dark mode, but the only way i know i can do that is by having the context instance from the widget build. as i said earlier, this array is just there so it can be mapped in the Calculator_screen.dart component... if you need more information please let me know

Please check the updated answer. I believe, using application context will solve your issues.
